How to extract text from a .docx file using .NET on Linux system?
I would like to retrieve text from a .docx file using the NPOI library, I want the code to run on Linux. The problem is that the code retrieves text that is not in the page layout ( on a red background) while it does not retrieve that which is in some layout as in the example image below. How to fix this? Is it possible using the NPOI library? Or are there any other replacements for open soruce libraries that work on Linux and will allow me to have such functionality?
example image
public string ExtractFromDocx(string filePath)
{
try
{
    using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(stream);

        // Extract text from paragraphs
        string text = "";
        foreach (XWPFParagraph p in doc.Paragraphs)
        {
            text += p.ParagraphText + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        return text;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred while extracting text from document: {ex.Message}");
    return string.Empty;
}

}

Could share some docx file with a text outside the page layout?
